How to solve | error no named parameter with name 'size' context : found this candidate, but argument dont match
Error: No named parameter with the name 'Size' Context: Found this candidate , butt the arguments don't match
I have try flutter clean & pub upgrade and change version flutter_star_prnt in pubspec.yaml but still got error

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_star_prnt-2.4.1/lib/src/print_commands.dart:205:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'Size'. 
Size : Logicalsize, ^^^^^

../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:28:9: Contetxt: Found this candidate, but the arguments dont match. 
const ViewConfiguration({ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BULD FAILED in 31s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

this my flutter version detail
environment: sdk: '>=2.12.0 <4.0.0'
flutter 3.19.6 dart sdk - 3.3.4
I try downgrade my flutter version to 3.16.9, then flutter pub upgrade , flutter clean & dart fix,and change version flutter_star_prnt in pubspec.yaml but still got error
this is my flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.2, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64, locale en-ID)
• Flutter version 3.19.2 on channel stable at /Users/shen/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 7482962148 (5 months ago), 2024-02-27 16:51:22 -0500
• Engine revision 04817c99c9
• Dart version 3.3.0
• DevTools version 2.31.1
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/shen/Library/Android/sdk
✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
✗ Android license status unknown.
Run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15F31d
• CocoaPods version 1.15.2
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.3)
• VS Code at /Users/shen/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension can be installed from:
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
• VS Code at /Users/shen/Downloads/Visual Studio Code-2.app/Contents
• Flutter extension can be installed from:
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
• macOS (desktop)              • macos         • darwin-x64  • macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64
[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
Process finished with exit code 0

add_product_seo_screen.dart - is that your code? Can you show us the bit that's trying to call TextfieldTags? Please edit it into the question.

I'd guess you've upgraded textfield_tags past a breaking change so you'll need to either roll back to the original version your code was written for, or fix your code to use the version you've upgraded to.

i have uploaded add_product_seo_screen.dart in question

i have to try fix code  but still got error

@Rup thanks . textfield_tag problem fixed! just fix code with version upgraded.

@Rup How about with Error: No named parameter with the name 'Size'

Same issue I expect: you'll need to work out why your code is trying to pass it, why the function you're calling doesn't expect it, and how to get the right data across in whatever new way it supports. Apologies I don't know these libraries or Dart really.
